# Expected number of cycles in a random tournament

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, expected-value, random-graphs

What is the expected number of cycles (of each length, if you like) in a tournament of order $n$ where the direction of each edge is decided uniformly at random?

The case $n = 3$ is trivial to calculate exactly, and I computed estimates for $n \leq 10$, but I'm sure there's a nice way to determine this with a counting argument or recurrence relation.

Comment: What have you tried, or alternatively, where did you find this problem (why does it interest you)?

Comment: I was drawing some graphs of (actual, real-life) tournaments, which led me to David, H. A., Ranking the Players in a Round Robin Tournament. _Review of the International Statistical Institute_, 39(2) 137-147. and just thinking about tournaments in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_G$ be the number of directed cycles in a random tournament $G$ of order $n$ where the direction of each edge is decided uniformly at random. Now, for each undirected cycle $C$ in $G$, define the random variable

$$X_C=\begin{cases}
1&\text{ if $C$ is a directed cycle in $G$}\\
0&\text{ if $C$ is not a directed cycle in $G$}\\
\end{cases}$$

and note that $X_G=\sum_{C\in\mathcal U} X_C$ where $\mathcal{U}$ is the set of undirected cycles $C$ in $G$. By the linearity of expectation, we may write

$$\mathbb{E}[X_G]=\sum_{C\in\mathcal{U}}\mathbb{E}[X_C]=\sum_{C\in\mathcal{U}}\mathbb{P}(C\text{ is a directed cycle in } G)$$

Now all that remains is to note that for $k\geq 3$, the probability that an undirected $k$-cycle $C$ in $G$ is a directed cycle in $G$ is given by $\frac1{2^{k-1}}$, and the number of undirected $k$-cycles $C$ in $G$ is given by $\binom{n}{k}\frac{(k-1)!}2$. Therefore, the expected number of directed cycles in a random tournament $G$ of order $n$ is

$$\mathbb{E}[X_G]=\sum_{k=3}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(k-1)!}{2^k}$$

Comment: This is convincing, although for $n \geq 6$ it disagrees (dramatically, as $n$ gets large) with my simulated observations. E.g. for $n = 6$ your formula says there ought to be 17 cycles on average, while I observe about 30.8 over 10,000 random tournaments. Maybe my code is just lousy.

Comment: @jdonland Your comment concerned for a second, but I've checked things over, and I do think the expression is accurate. For another source (without proof), the introduction of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.06577) claims that the expected number of  directed $\ell$-cycles in an $n$-vertex tournament is $\frac{(\ell-1)!}{2^\ell}\binom{n}{\ell}$, which is equivalent to what I've written.